# Is there a difference between CPU and Memory Usage of Collections versus ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Recently I've been making Bukkit Minecraft plugins in Eclipse for a project and I've been using an arraylist to store the player objects. After some messing around trying to optimise my code, I realised that there is another way to define said List of objects using a java Collection. Now I have the basics down which is that a collection, unlike an arraylist, does not allow you to reference a variable based on the index but I'm not using that in my code so I was wondering if there are any other advantages regarding CPU or memory usage?
Note* I do know that by passing the variable around as a Collection it's easier to cast it to other forms of lists but I'm confident I won't be doing this in my code so I wouldn't be regarding this as an advantage.

Comment: `ArrayList` is one of the most efficient collection in terms of memory usage (it's essentially an array of references) - I'm not sure what you expect to gain in that respect when switching to something else.

Comment: This whole question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding.  `Collection` is an interface not a class, and that makes questions about CPU & memory performance of `Collection` meaningless.  I recommend that you take the time to read a Java tutorial or a Java textbook.  It will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection` isn't a class, it's an interface.  That is, it doesn't actually *do* anything; it just defines which methods are available.  In fact, `ArrayList` supports the `Collection` interface.  So, you can do this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But you can do the following, and they are *functionally identical*:

```
Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, in the latter example, because you are now referencing the `ArrayList` as a `Collection`, you only have access to the the methods on `Collection`, which, as you have discovered, is a lot more restricted than `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList` also supports the `List` interface, which itself extends `Collection`, and provides the additional list methods, so you can do this (and this is generally recommended):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

So the performance of `Collection` vs `ArrayList` isn't really a valid question. What I think you *want* to know is the comparative performance of different `List` implementations.  The main single-threaded implementations in Java are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.  These are created like this:

```
List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

You will find plenty of materials out there with the pros and cons of each. For example: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)